# expression blend coloured regions

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

I am working with expression blend and c# to create a silverlight site. I would like to create a map of the world which has many regions. on clicking on the region the colour changes. I have already created the regions.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do, make the region change color when you click on it?

Comment: yes that is what I am trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the regions created already, when you get the click event you need to change the colour of the region. Normally this would be the background property of the control, though it can depend on what control you used to represent a region?

**Edit in response to comment**

Since you're using rectangle and other shapes **Fill** is the property you will be changing.

Comment: is it a good idea to use a coloured copy instead a particular continent rather than a normal shape, then use the collapsed property? Because I am trying that and it doesnt seem to like the idea. The map collapsed perfectly whilst the region keeps appearing in all of the frames :S